# How to deal with almost the same enums?

Tags: asp.net, enums, refactoring

I need to define **enums** in several classes to represent available actions for each class. . Now I wonder what is the best way to deal with this?

1) Create separate enums

```
public enum Foo {Insert, Update, Delete , Select };
public enum Bar {Insert, Select };
```

2) or use a general `enum` for all of them

```
public enum FooBar {Insert, Update, Delete , Select};
```

Edit : I want to use this enums in class methods parameters

```
public void MethodOne(Foo action){ ...}
```

Comment: Does your code logic require to know from all classes which implements the Insert action?

Comment: @StefanP. : no .by the way , I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer **should come from your domain - ubiquitous language**

However, I think that you are going to get into troubles if you implement a new enumeration for each class, this approach is going to be error-prone and it's going to confuse your developers. Now imagine the poor guys that will have to maintain your code in the future...

If you insist in using enumerations, I think it would be better to create s single enumeration named: `Actions` and use it consistently across your application

If you want  a more elegant solution, I would recommend you to consider the [State pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx#_self1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use inheritance to define your enums - at least sort of.

Try this:

```
public class Bar
{
    public static readonly int Insert = 1;
    public static readonly int Select = 2;
}

public class Foo : Bar
{
    public static readonly int Update = 3;
    public static readonly int Delete = 4;
}
```

You still use the code like an enum - `Bar.Insert` or `Foo.Select` or `Foo.Delete`.

Does this help?